# Using a for loop to add a new line to a table: python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to create a .bed file after searching through DNA sequences for two regular expressions. Ideally, I'd like to generate a tab-separated file which contains the sequence description, the start location of the first regex and the end location of the second regex. I know that the regex section works, it's just creating the \t separated file I am struggling with.

I was hoping that I could open/create a file and simply print a new line for each iteration of the `for loop` that contains this information, like so:

```
with open("Mimp_hits.bed", "a+") as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        print(f'{sequence.description}\t{h.start()}\t{h_rc.end()}')
file_object.close()
```

But this doesn't seem to work (creates empty file). I have also tried to use `file_object.write`, but again this creates an empty file too.

This is all of the code I have including searching for the regexes:

```
import re, sys

from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord

infile = sys.argv[1]

for sequence in SeqIO.parse(infile, "fasta"):
    hit = re.finditer(r"CAGTGGG..GCAA[TA]AA", str(sequence.seq))
    mimp_length = 400
    for h in hit:
        h_start = h.start()
        hit_rc = re.finditer(r"TT[TA]TTGC..CCCACTG", str(sequence.seq))
        for h_rc in hit_rc:
            h_rc_end = h_rc.end()
            length = h_rc_end - h_start
            if length > 0:
                if length < mimp_length:
                    with open("Mimp_hits.bed", "a+") as file_object:
                        for line in file_object:
                            print(sequence.description, h.start(), h_rc.end())
                    file_object.close()
```

This is the desired output:

```
Focub_II5_mimp_1__contig_1.16(656599:656809)    2   208
Focub_II5_mimp_2__contig_1.47(41315:41540)  2   223
Focub_II5_mimp_3__contig_1.65(13656:13882)  2   224
Focub_II5_mimp_4__contig_1.70(61591:61809)  2   216
```

This is example input:

```
>Focub_II5_mimp_1__contig_1.16(656599:656809)
TACAGTGGGATGCAAAAAGTATTCGCAGGTGTGTAGAGAGATTTGTTGCTCGGAAGCTAGTTAGGTGTAGCTTGTCAGGTTCTCAGTACCCTATATTACACCGAGATCAGCGGGATAATCTAGTCTCGAGTACATAAGCTAAGTTAAGCTACTAACTAGCGCAGCTGACACAACTTACACACCTGCAAATACTTTTTGCATCCCACTGTA
>Focub_II5_mimp_2__contig_1.47(41315:41540)
TACAGTGGGAGGCAATAAGTATGAATACCGGGCGTGTATTGTTTTCTGCCGCTAGCCCATTTTAACAGCTAGAGTGTGTATATTAACCTCACACATAGCTATCTCTTATACTAATTGGTTAGGGAAAACCTCTAACCAGGATTAGGAGTCAACATAGCTTGTTTTAGGCTAAGAGGTGTGTGTCAGTACACCAAAGGGTATTCATACTTATTGCCCCCCACTGTA
>Focub_II5_mimp_3__contig_1.65(13656:13882)
TACAGTGGGAGGCAATAAGTATGAATACCGGGCGTGTATTGTTTTTCTGCCGCTAGCCTATTTTAATAGTTAGAGTGTGCATATTAACCTCACACATAGCTATCTTATATACTAATCGGTTAGGGAAAACCTCTAACCAGGATTAGGAGTCAACATAGCTTCTTTTAGGCTAAGAGGTGTGTGTCAGTACACCAAAGGGTATTCATACTTATTGCCCCCCACTGTA
>Focub_II5_mimp_4__contig_1.70(61591:61809)
TACAGTGGGATGCAATAAGTTTGAATGCAGGCTGAAGTACCAGCTGTTGTAATCTAGCTCCTGTATACAACGCTTTAGCTTGATAAAGTAAGCGCTAAGCTGTATCAGGCAAAAGGCTATCCCGATTGGGGTATTGCTACGTAGGGAACTGGTCTTACCTTGGTTAGTCAGTGAATGTGTACTTGAGTTTGGATTCAAACTTATTGCATCCCACTGTA
```

Is anybody able to help?

Thank you :)

Comment: you are opening the file for `a+` as in you intend to append to it, but then you iterate over it? What is your intent?

Comment: The inputs: sequence.description, h.start(), h_rc.end() are identified while searching for the regex. If I use this outside of the for line in file_object: loop, it prints the desired output.

Comment: Tadhg McDonald-Jensen, I believed that I would need to iterate over it to create a new line. Is this unnecessary?

Comment: if your intent is to add a line to the file then just do `print(..., file=file_object)` to write the line to the file (no looping over the file), if this is the desired behaviour I can post an answer with more detail.

Comment: using: print(sequence.description, h.start(), h_rc.end(), file=file_object) without the loop does indeed provide the desired output! Thank you, how do I ensure it is tab-separated? Also, if you are willing, an answer with more detail would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You don't need `file_object.close()`, it's automatically closed by `with`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to write a line to a file you would do something like this:

```
with open("file.txt", "a") as f:
    print("new line", file=f)
```

and if you want it tab separated you can also add `sep="\t"`, this is why python 3 made [`print` a function](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#print) so you can use `sep`, `end`, `file`, and `flush` keyword arguments. :)

opening a file for appending means the file pointer starts at the end of the file which means that writing to it doesn't override any data (gets appended to the end of the file) and iterating over it (or otherwise reading from it) gives nothing like you already reached the end of the file.

So instead of iterating over the lines of the file you would just write the single line to it:

```
                with open("Mimp_hits.bed", "a") as file_object:
                    print(sequence.description, h.start(), h_rc.end(), file=file_object)
```

you can also consider just opening the file near the beginning of the loop since opening it once and writing multiple times is more efficient than opening it multiple times, also the with block automatically closes the file so no need to do that explicitly.

Comment: I didn't know about the `file` parameter to `print` - that's very handy, thanks.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I have amened my code and it now works splendidly. I should probably google this or create a new post... but while I have you I was wondering if there is a way to set a variable to name the file? e.g. "{infile}_mimp_hits.bed" . I have just tried this but it literally names the output file {infile}_mimp_hits.bed, rather than, say input.fasta_mimp_hits.bed.

Comment: if you are using python 3.7 or up you can [use an `f-string`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), so `f"{infile}_mimp_hits.bed"`, earlier versions you'd use `"{}_mimp_hits.bed".format(infile)` or since `infile` is just a string, doing `infile + "_mimp_hits.bed"` would also work.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to open the file in "a+" mode, and loop over lines from it (which will not find anything because the file is positioned at the end when you do that).  In any case, if this is an output file only, then you would open it in "a" mode to append to it.

Probably you just want to open the file once for appending, and inside the `with` statement, do your main loop, using `file_object.write(...)` when you want to actually append strings to the file.  Note that there is no need for `file_object.close()` when using this `with` construct.

```
with open("Mimp_hits.bed", "a") as file_object:
    for sequence in SeqIO.parse(infile, "fasta"):
        # ... etc per original code ...
                    if length < mimp_length:
                        file_object.write("{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(
                                sequence.description, h.start(), h_rc.end()))
```

Comment: Just noticed that it asks for tab-separated output, so I edited this to use `\t`

Comment: Thank you for you response, I was not aware of the differences between "a+" and "a" mode :)

Comment: @Jpike The various modes with "+" are different variants on files opened for both reading and writing. See list of access modes at e.g. https://stackabuse.com/file-handling-in-python/